# Magento 2: Adding a new block to a child theme

Tags: magento2, layout, template, xml, parent-child-theme

Just getting to grips with Magento 2.. I have created and applied a child theme of Luma that seems to work fine. It pulls in my CSS files and things like that. But I would like to add some custom blocks to the footer.

Here are the contents of my default.xml which is in mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

As you can see I've tried to create a new block called footer_social, I have then created a .phtml file which sits in mtheme/Magento_Theme/html/footer_social.phtml and added a little bit of text to it to test but nothing changes. Guessing I am missing something? Any help appreciated.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">148</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">43</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="footer_social" template="Magento_Theme::html/footer_social.phtml">
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
        <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

since the store switcher is already added in the luma theme, you should not add it again in your theme to the footer (to be honest I'm not 100% sure if it gets overridden or maybe cause an error when you add a block with the same name)

For your issue, I think it's just an xml fault. You did not close the block tag correctly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231902/self-closing-tags-in-xml-files

Just try this (trailing slash added):

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="footer_social" template="Magento_Theme::html/footer_social.phtml"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried what you mentioned and the problem persists. My block is still not visible on the site. I have been wondering if my link to the template phtml file is correct. Magento_Theme:: will always reference my child theme template directory?

Comment: Ok sorted! I didn't realise Magento_Theme::html actually references my_theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/